# tvOS - TVML background-color

Tags: tvos, tvml

Just started with TVML for Apple tvOS the other day. And I'm stuck..

Trying to set the background-color to a rgba for a reviewCard in TVML, but there are no changes..

`background-color: rgba(255,255,255,100);`

Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried putting (x, x, x, 1) instead of (x, x, x, 100)? - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ITMLStyles.html

Comment: Yes i have. But it was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute background-color for rgba is red,blue,green,alpha.

Red,blue,green can be set in a range from 0 to 255.
Alpha however, can only be set in a range from 0.0 to 1.0

If you just want to make it full color, only set rgb without the alpha attribute, it will set 1.0 automatically.